# javascript syntax indenting wysiwyg editor creating tabs with regular expression, divs and classes (no jQuery please)

Tags: javascript, css, regex, wysiwyg

I am trying to make a simple wysiwig editor that is capable of creating a text indentation for parent and child sections with turnary operators in javascript. The language is for a DJ software Virtual DJ, but it looks and functions the exactly the same as javascript.

an example of the sort of code I want to sort is

```
query1 ? query2 ? "query1 and query2 are true" : "query1 is true but query2 is false" : query3 ? "query1 and query2 are false but query3 is true" : "all queries are false"
```

essentially what I want to do is wrap the parent condition in a div with css giving it padding to look like tabs. I tried JSFiddle to make an example but no luck getting the feedback I was after so I spent a couple of hours making one that updates the HTML live when it's dynamically inserted. There are instructions on the page including an abstracted function to make string.replace a little easier to work with the page.

There are two examples on the page of what I am after, one is the innerHTML and one is the displayed content with formatting. I'm probably not going to use classNames, I will use CSS3 selectors to control how much indent a line will have as I can easily target childnodes that way.

thanks for any help, I have been wrestling with this for a while and the only thing I can think of to fix it is to reverse the string and do the matching from the end, but that wasn't working out how I though it would.

The page is also on my mates server if you think you can help
http://action-jackson.com.au/indentTest.html

Thanks again,

andrew.

----EDIT-----------------------------------------

Sorry for not explaining it properly the first time. I though the examples on the webpage would suffice.

Specifically I want to indent the code from a string entry so the string or something like it would be given by the user from an XML config file. Then I wanted to use the RegEx to put in the appropriate tags to allow it to be displayed on the page indented.. The problem is I use very large scripts for this program eg

```
var 'jog_fx' 0 ? param_greater 0% ? effect 'qb_filter' slider 3 +0.006 & effect 'ramp_delay' slider 1 +0.007 : effect 'qb_filter' slider 3 -0.005 & effect 'ramp_delay' slider 1 -0.007 : var 'jog_fx' 1 ? param_greater 0% ? effect 'crusher' slider 1 +0.005 & effect 'ramp_delay' slider 1 +0.005 : effect 'crusher' slider 1 -0.005 & effect 'ramp_delay' slider 1 -0.005 : var 'jog_fx' 2 ? param_smaller 0% ? effect 'trans' slider 1 -0.002 & effect 'flanjet' slider 1 -0.001 & effect 'qb_filter' slider 3 -0.002 & effect 'tal-reverb-2' slider 3 -0.001 & effect 'tal-reverb-2' slider 2 +0.0005  : effect 'trans' slider 1 -0.002 & effect 'flanjet' slider 1 +0.001 & effect 'qb_filter' slider 3 +0.002 & effect 'tal-reverb-2' slider 3 +0.001 & effect 'tal-reverb-2' slider 2 -0.0005 : var 'jog_fx' 3 ? param_greater 0% ? effect '3p_delay' slider 1 +0.002 : effect '3p_delay' slider 1 -0.002 : var 'jog_fx' 4 ? effect 'ramp_delay' slider 1 : var 'jog_fx' 5 ? device_side 'left' ? param_greater 0% ? param_multiply 25% & effect 'rollit' slider 3 +0.001 & effect 'rollit' slider 2 +0.001 : param_multiply 25% & effect 'rollit' slider 3 -0.001 & effect 'rollit' slider 2 -0.001 : param_greater 0% ? param_multiply 25% & effect 'rollit2' slider 3 +0.001 & effect 'rollit2' slider 2 +0.001 : param_multiply 25% & effect 'rollit2' slider 3 -0.001 & effect 'rollit2' slider 2 -0.001 : var 'jog_fx' 6 ? param_greater 0% ? effect 'gate_echo' slider +0.01 : effect 'gate_echo' slider 1 -0.01 : var 'jog_fx' 7 ? param_greater 0% ? effect 'multitap delay' slider +0.003 : effect 'multitap delay' slider 1 -0.003 : var 'jog_fx' 8 ? param_greater 0% ? param_multiply 25% & effect 'instajungle' slider 11 +0.01 : param_multiply 25% & effect 'instajungle' slider 11 -0.01 : touchwheel
```

I was thinking I could use the CSS3 selectors [p:nth-child(n), p:nth-last-child(n)]

to add padding/margin/left to the element for indentation, but that didn't really work out how I planned. What I think I need to do is get only the parts of the string that have /\?([^:]:)/ 'start with "? anything :" then get the parts that have /\?([^\?])/, "? anything ?" and finally /:([^:])(:)/, ": anything :" and just add tags to it eg. using the regie() function on the page.

```
log(regie(str, [/\?([^\?]*)(/?)/g, /\?([^:]*)(\:)/g, /:([^:])(:)/g], ['</div>$1 <div class="forwards">$2 </div>', '</div>$1 <div class="forwards">$2</div>', '</div>$1 <div class="backwards">$2 </div>',]));
```

---

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Suite</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- <link href='indent.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
<style type='text/css'>
 body{   background: #17191a;   color: #aaa;   font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', sans-serif;   overflow:none;  }   #content{   width: 1800px;   height: 940px;   margin:auto;  }   #outputs{   width: 1060px;   float:left;  }   .wrapperHouse{   width: 492px;   height: 450px;   position:relative;   overflow:hidden;   float:left;   margin: 10px;   padding:0;  }   .wrapper{   overflow:hidden;   height:500px;   width: 500px;   height: 450px;   background: #27292A;   float:left;   overflow:hidden;  }   .scroll{   overflow:hidden;   height:1000px;   width: 500px;   position: relative;   top: -295px;   z-index:0;   transition:0.2s all;   padding: 300px 0;  }   .bg{   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #111 inset,0 0 10px #222 inset;   background: #1d1f20;   background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #1d1f20 1%, #2e2f30 99%);   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(1%,#1d1f20), color-stop(99%,#2e2f30));   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #1d1f20 1%,#2e2f30 99%);   background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #1d1f20 1%,#2e2f30 99%);   background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #1d1f20 1%,#2e2f30 99%);   background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #1d1f20 1%,#2e2f30 99%);   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1d1f20', endColorstr='#2e2f30',GradientType=1 );  }   .bgh{   background: #35383a;   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #35383a 0%, #131619 99%);   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#35383a), color-stop(99%,#131619));   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #35383a 0%,#131619 99%);   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #35383a 0%,#131619 99%);   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #35383a 0%,#131619 99%);   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #35383a 0%,#131619 99%);   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#35383a', endColorstr='#131619',GradientType=0 );  }   .bg:focus{   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #111 inset,0 0 10px #17199a inset;  }   #scriptHouse, #scriptWrapperHouse{   width: 700px;   height: 920px;   padding:0;  }   #scriptWindow{   background: #27292A;   width: 700px;   height: 920px;  }   .scriptWrapper h2{   width: 700px;   transition:0.5s all;  }   .scriptWrapper h2:hover{   text-shadow:0 0 10px #099CC9;   cursor: pointer;  }   #innerScript{   width: 660px;   height: 1820px;   padding:200px 20px;   font-family: monospace;   font-size: 1.1em;   margin:0;   position: relative;   top: -180px;  }   .indent{   padding-left: 25px;   }   .true{   color: #099CC9;  }   .false{   color:#ae4343;  }   .query{   color: #ada243;  }   .string, .comment{   color:#43aed8;  }   .func{   color:#c244d6;  }   h2{   background: #000000;   font-family: sans-serif;   text-align: center;   padding:0;   padding-top:10px;   margin:0;   width: 492px;   height:50px;   background: #1a1c1e;   border:1px solid #212325;   transition:0.5s all;   z-index:5;   position: relative;   top:0px;  }   h2:hover{   text-shadow:0 0 10px #099CC9;   cursor: pointer; } pre{left:-30px;}    

</style>
<body onload="check()">

<section id="content">

    <section id="outputs">

    <section class="wrapperHouse">
    <div class="h2House bg"><h2 class="bgh">
                inner html example
            </h2></div>
        <div id="pageHtml" class="bg wrapper">

            <pre id="pre1" class="scroll"></pre> 
        </div>
    </section>

<section class="wrapperHouse">
<header class="h2House bg"><h2 class="bgh">output of html example</h2></header>     
    <div id="indentHouse" class="bg wrapper">
        <div id="innerIndent" class="scroll">
            <div class="indent">
                query1 ? 
                <div class="indent">
                    query2 ? 
                    <div class="indent">
                        query1 are and query2 are true :
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="indent">
                    query1 is true but query2 is false :
                </div>
                <div class="indent">query3 ?
                    <div class="indent">
                        query1 and query2 are false but query3 is true :
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    all queries are false
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


        <section class="wrapperHouse">
            <header class="h2House bg"><h2 class="bgh" onclick="clearWindow()">inner html</h2></header>
            <div id="realHtmlHouse" class="bg wrapper">
                <pre id="realHtml" class="scroll"></pre>
            </div>
        </section>

    <section class="wrapperHouse">
        <div id="realOutputHouse" class="bg wrapper">
            <header class="h2House bg"><h2 class="bgh" onclick="clearWindow()">output html</h2></header>
            <div id="realOutputInner" class="scroll"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

</section>
    <section id="scriptWrapperHouse" class="wrapperHouse">
        <div class="scriptWrapper h2House bg"><h2 class="bgh" onclick="run()">click to run javascript</h2></div>
        <div id="scriptHouse" class="wrapper bg">
            <div id="scriptWindow">
                <div id="innerScript" class="scroll" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">
                    <p class="comment">// the string of text is stored in the variable 'str'</p>
                    <p class="comment">// the log to the windows use <span class="func">log(string);</span></p>
                    <p class="comment">// for an abstracted replace function use 
                    <br>// <span class="func">regie(string, search:array||string, replace:array||string, function:optional);</span>
                    <br>// if passing an array use regular expresson, string is for a single replace string that gets converted to RegExp
                    <br>// a function can be passed as an argument if it is necessary</p><br><p></p>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </section>   

</section> <!-- end content -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function id(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function tag(name){
        return document.getElementsByTagName(name);
    }

    function classs(name){
        return document.getElementsByClassName(name);
    }

    var output = id('realOutputInner');
    var str = "query1 ? query2 ? query1 are and query2 are true : query1 is true but query2 is false : query3 ? query1 and query2 are false but query3 is true : all queries are false";

    function log(text){
        //debugger;
        tag('pre')[1].innerHTML = text.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/(true|false|query)([0-9]*)/g, '<span class="$1">$1$2</span>');
        output.innerHTML = text.replace(/(true|false|query)([0-9]*)/g, '<span class="$1">$1$2</span>');
    };

    function clearWindow(){
        output.innerHTML = '';
        tag('pre')[1].innerHTML = '';
    };

    var comStyle = function(element , pseudoElt){
        if(!pseudoElt){pseudoElt = null}
        if(id(element).style.top != ''){
            return id(element).style
        } else {
            return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(element), pseudoElt);
        }
    }

    function regie(str, search, replacage, fn){
        var rep = str;
        //debugger;
        console.log('arg1: ' + arguments[1] + ' arg2: ' + arguments[2]);
        if(arguments.length < 4){
            console.log('3 args');
            if(typeof arguments[1] == 'string' && typeof arguments[2] == 'string'){
                search = new RegExp(search, 'g');
                str = str.replace(search, replacage);
            } else {
                console.log('args are not strings');
                for(var i = 0; i < search.length; i++){
                    if(search[i].test(str)){
                        str = str.replace(search[i], replacage[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log('4 args');
            if(typeof arguments[1] == 'string' && typeof arguments[2] == 'string'){
                for(var i = 0; i < search.length; i++){
                    if(search[i].test(str)){
                        str = str.replace(search[i], fn) + ' ';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for(var i = 0; i < search.length; i++){
                    if(search[i].test(str)){
                        str = str.replace(search[i], fn) + ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return str; 
    };

    function check(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            tag('pre')[i].innerHTML = regie(id('innerIndent').innerHTML, [/</g , /(true|false|query)([0-9]*)/g, /^\t\t/, /\t/g] , ['&lt;', '<span class="$1">$1$2</span>', '', '  ']);
        };
        console.log(id('innerIndent').innerHTML);
        id('indentHouse').innerHTML = regie(id('indentHouse').innerHTML, '(true|false|query)([0-9]*)' , '<span class="$1">$1$2</span>');
        id('realOutputInner').innerHTML = id('innerIndent').innerHTML;
    };

    function run(){
        var stuff = id('innerScript').innerText.replace(/<[a-z0-9 =\"\']*>/g, '');
        eval(stuff);
    };

        function displaywheel(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var scroll = classs('scroll');
            for (var i = 0; i < scroll.length; i++) {
                scroll[i].style.top = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(scroll[i].id), null).top;
            };
            //console.log(e.target);
        var evt=window.event || e;
        var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta;
        if(delta < 0){
            var pos = parseInt(e.target.style.top);
            pos -= 50;
                e.target.style.top = pos +'px';
            } else {
                var pos = parseInt(e.target.style.top);
                pos += 50;
                e.target.style.top = pos +'px';
            }
        }

        var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";

        (function(){
            var scroll = classs('wrapper');
            for (var i = 0; i < scroll.length; i++) {(function(x){
                    scroll[x].addEventListener(mousewheelevt, displaywheel, false);
                }(i));
            }
        })();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are several problems with your question. You should really try to point down the problem rather then posting the whole of your code. It's hard to understand what exactly you are asking. Second: you are trying to parse some syntax, which is recursive in nature using regular expressions, which just seems like a wrong tool (it won't suffice on its own). I haven't tried JS implementation of PEG http://pegjs.majda.cz/ but I tried PEG in other languages, and I would encourage you to try to use it for your task. Seems like it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated the explanation a little and provided an example of how to use the page, also page I put here isn't the page I'm trying to create it's a test bed to help with the task of adding tags dynamically to a string and showing how it is presented in the page and the output of the html

Comment: I may have come up with a solution... first replace all the the "? " and ": " with "$1 #, then split the string to an array using "#", fro there I think I only need to append and prepend tags and the approptiate class to move the div forward or backward..... regie(str, "(\\?|:)\\s", "$1 #").split(/\#/);

Comment: Seriously, you should try PEG, it is a very nice (and more expressive) substitute to regexps, it will spare you all this monkey business with layers of replacements.